# Determining location of text input caret location globally on screen in Windows

Tags: windows, autohotkey

My aim is to display a little overlay, a flag icon, for the chosen keyboard layout, etc. at the exact location where one would type something, as to help the user immediately see which input layout is being used (for example US vs JP layout).

I would like to do this not per application, but globally.

My first attempt to do this was to listen for various Microsoft Windows specific events, when the caret changes, and so on, but apps like Slack for example work differently than native Windows apps so this is hard to do.

My other idea is to track the caret's blinking motion over the screen (taking screenshots periodically and detecting where the caret is blinking).

Not sure how sound these ideas are, but this question is attempt the find the best possible solution to do this.

Thank you for all your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

A_CaretX and A_CaretY in autohotkey(V1 version) maybe help you
see https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#misc

Comment: For those using AHK version 2, `A_CaretY` and `A_CaretX` are no longer supported, use `CaretGetPos()` instead. (https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/commands/CaretGetPos.htm)